# Unable to generate a pem cert of public key using secure enclave keys

Tags: ios, security, x509, pem

I want to generate a pem certificate of the public key in iOS using secure enclave. swift-certificates works fine if used with keys generated outside secure enclave. Since my keys are generated inside secure enclave private key is not accessible and so swift-certificate is not working.

Is there any way I can generate a PEM cert of public key natively using Security or internal frameworks? If not, is there any way this can be done using swift-certificates?

```
    // Not working
    func generateCertWithSecureEnclave(subjectName: String) {
        let keyPair: (publicKey: SecKey, privateKey: SecKey) = getKeyPair()!
        
        var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
        guard let publicKey = SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation(keyPair.publicKey, &error) as? Data else {
            assertionFailure("Failed to get public key")
            return
        }
        
        var signingPublicKey: P256.Signing.PublicKey!
        do {
            signingPublicKey = try P256.Signing.PublicKey(x963Representation: publicKey)
        } catch {
            return
        }
        
        do {
            let bytes = signingPublicKey.derRepresentation.copyBytes(as: UInt8.self)
            let certificate = try Certificate(derEncoded: bytes)
            print("Certificate: ", try? certificate.serializeAsPEM().pemString)
        } catch {
            print("Certificate error: Certificate generation error - \(error)")
        }
    }
```